# Objective C compiler not complaining about syntax error

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to figure out why gcc is OK with the following:

```
- (void) methodname: (id) sender;
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Notice what's wrong here: There is a semicolon that should not be there.
I'm also finding that execution of the method is having bizarre results.

Anybody know what effect the semicolon is supposed to have or not have here?

Thanks.

Comment: I just tried this on one of my methods, and it appears that the `;` is just completely ignored (at least in my case). What bizarre results are you getting? By the way, whatever problems doing this causes can be easily avoided by not doing this in the first place. :)

Comment: It the compiler doesn't complain about it, it is not a syntax error.

Comment: What's happening is that although the method is executed (at then end of an async http get operation), the call within it to UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString is not.

Answer (score 2):

The semi-colon is optional in the context of the `@implementation`.   Some teams standardize on requiring it, some don't.

Answer (score 0):

In general ; makes it a function prototype. But the compiler must be smart enough to ignore it in this case. I don't think it's the ; that's causing your odd issues but I'm not sure.

Comment: Agreed, then maybe it's interpreting the braces as simple a code block.

Comment: The code does seem happier now that I've removed the semicolon.

Comment: There is no difference between having and not having the semicolon in the @implementation after method declarations.  Nothing changed. Thinking that your code 'is happier' as a result of a non-change is a sure fire way start down the path of creating unmaintainable code.

Comment: did he just kick your puppy or something?